# Mudar propriedades de uma div com um clique

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<div id="personalizada">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="balao"></div>
```

Gostaria de quando eu clicar em id="personalizada" a opacidade de id="balao" mude para 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso?

```js
function mudaOpacidade() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("balao")[0].style.opacity=1;
}
```

```css
.balao {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="personalizada" onclick="mudaOpacidade()">
  Cliqyaqui
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="balao"></div>
```

Com jquery seria:

```js
$("#personalizada").on("click",function(){
$(".balao").css("opacity",1);
});
```

```css
.balao {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="personalizada">
  Clique aqui
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="balao"></div>
```